# Thymeleaf: `th:value` in option is getting split at "," resulting in two values instead of one

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have a list of states including:

- germany
- iran, islamic republic
- england
- ....

I put this list into a multiple selection input:

```html
<select th:field="*{statesSelection}" multiple="multiple">
  <option
    th:each="state : ${states}"
    th:value="${state}"
    th:text="${state}"></option>
</select>
```

The ui element renders correctly and also the source inspection of the browser shows me that everything is correctly set.

The java data transfer object:

```java
public class Selection implements Serializable {
    ...
    private List<String> statesSelection = new ArrayList<>();
    ...
}
```

And the actual endpoint:

```java
@RequestMapping(value = "/select")
public String select(Model model, @ModelAttribute Selection selection) {

}
```

*The Problem*

After I selected `iran, islamic republic` and press submit, the endpoint does not
get a list with a single entry `iran, islamic republic` it is getting a list of
two entries: `iran` and `islamic republic` so the value is getting split up at `,`.

How can I prevent that from happening?

**EDIT**

I just realized that the problem only occurs if `iran, islamic republic` is the only value that I select. As soon as I select a second value together with iran the problem does not occur.

Comment: URL Encode the values. The `,` is used (normally) to separate values in a single parameter (which is what you experience now). You must encode the value so the `,` becomes a `%2C` and the ` ` becomes a `+`. That way the value will be properly sent.

Comment: Hi, thx for that hint. Is it really url encoding? the ` ` (space) is no problem at all. For example `iran islamic republic` is working just fine, the `,` is the only problem I faced so far.

Comment: Spaces might appear to not be a problem eventually they become a problem. Everything you send needs to be URL encoded.

Comment: I just noticed another thing, I will update my post. The problem only occurs if I select only one. If I select multiple values that problem does not occur.

Comment: Multiple values will, probably, lead to automatic URL encoding, whilst a single value doesn't.

Comment: Possible for sure. I assume I would need to url encode the value in the html template because If I url encode the value on the backend side the value would also show url encoded on the label for the user. Any idea how to url encode the value from inside the html template?

Comment: I will try this and give feedback: https://frontbackend.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-utility-methods-for-uri-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I tried to use the following:

```html
<select th:field="*{statesSelection}" multiple="multiple">
  <option
    th:each="state : ${states}"
    th:value="${#uris.escapePath(state)}"
    th:text="${state}"></option>
</select>
```

But that resulted in the following: `iran, %20islamic%20republic` which in the backend resulted in:

- iran
- %20islamic%20republic

So to things:

1. It does not get automatically url encoded / decoded.
2. Value is still splitted.

I found a solution for the problem:

1. I URL encode all values in the backend
2. Send them to the frontend
3. URL decode the values in the label text
4. Send selected values to the backend
5. URL Decode values in the backend

```html
<select th:field="*{statesSelection}" multiple="multiple">
  <option
    th:each="state : ${states}"
    th:value="${state}"
    th:text="${#string.replace(#uris.unescapePath(state), '+', ' ')}"></option>
</select>
```

I need to replace + with   because java URL Encoder is encoding spaces to the + symbol.